# @CompoundIndex not working in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, indexing, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on an application using Spring Data MongoDB. I would like to create a compound index on one of my models. I have added a @CompoundIndex annotation at the top like so:

```
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "name_", def = "{ 'tenantId': 1, 'name': 1 }", unique = true)
})
public class MyModel {

}
```

However, the index is not created. I have also tried to directly place the `@CompoundIndex` above the class. The collection is still missing the index. The same index definition is working fine when created like so:

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps(MyModel.class).ensureIndex(new Index().named("name_").on("tenantId", Direction.ASC).on("name", Direction.ASC).unique());
```

I'd prefer to use the annotation-based definition of the index. Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Have you tried http://pastebin.com/PynPCgRY ?

Comment: I did now and it does not change the behavior...

Comment: Hi! May I ask you to post the whole application ? It would be great if you're able to provide the Spring context at least.

Comment: I had the same problem, index was not created using the annotation, but it was created using ensureIndex explicitly. The i realised i was missing the Document annotaton. Now the index is created  with the CompundIndex annotation.

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now in Spring Boot 1.4 with Spring Data Mongo 1.9.2 and the Mongo 3.2 java driver.

Comment: Have you find an answer? my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847601/spring-data-mongodb-unable-to-find-index-via-mongo

Answer (score 17):

You need to add the following to `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

or in `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      auto-index-creation: true
```

Comment: 4 years later and finding this bit of documentation is still difficult. but it fixed my problem - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Couple years later, I faced the same issue. If none of above answers work for you (just like for me), try overriding `autoIndexCreation()` in `MongoConfig` class.

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
  @Override
  protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would rather go with mongodb **createIndex** method as it ensures indexes have been created, even if you created them in your app models (Spring boot in this case) it's always better to do a double check and create them manually https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/