# Spring boot / mongo wont create index with the index annotation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have the following:

```
@Document(collection = "linkmetadata")
public class LinkMetaData {
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String url;
...
}
```

But whenever it creates the collection it doesn't create any index for the url field, it's like it just ignores the annotation. Any idea why this is?

Edit: no index is created upon insertion of data either. And when I try to fetch data for a specific url it throws an error that the url key is not unique if I entered the same url twice, but it doesn't care about inserting the unique key since there is no index..

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73114651/11485546) answer if none of the above works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I had another collection also with a url field marked as unqiue. I had to specify the name of the index on one of them otherwise it seems that it considered that the index already exists even though it was on two different collections

```
@Indexed(name = "meta_url_index_unique", unique = true)
private String url;
```

Answer (score 45):

Add below line in your `application.properties`

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true
```

Comment: this property needs to be enabled, after 3.0

Comment: You deserve a medal

Comment: Does this property create (re-create) the indexes every time the service is started or works like data migration and don't re-create is already present?

Comment: Idk if anyone else got it, but when I add that line in my application.properties. It gives me a UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This answer was before the author updates his question

I believe you need to use the @Document annotation on top the class declaration

So your class should be

```
@Document
public class LinkMetaData {
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String url;
...
}
```

Comment: I did i just didn't include eveyrthing on top, ill update the question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Can you include the configuration you used to enable mongo

Comment: The configuration is on our config server I don't have access to it at this very moment. But it works with other collections in the same service that have unique indexes created by annotations.

Comment: I figured it out, posted an answer

Comment: really thanks bro, didint know @Document was obligatory

Answer (score 2):

I Also had the same issue. The one that solved my issue was adding the index from the mongo db level

```
db.city.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a high chance that you already have duplicates in your collection hence failing to create the index.

Check if you have duplicate URL values, if so, that should be your issue. Then you can drop the collection if it's not "PROD" data/ collection", then re-try, it should go through.