# Why @Indexed is not creating an index in MongoDB? (MongoDB, Morphia, Spring Data)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, morphia

Why is Morphia's @Indexed annotation is not creating index in Mongo DB?

```
  //@Indexed(name = "_ts", expireAfterSeconds = 7200) //This was written earlier which was not working and it is deprecated too

    @Indexed(options = @IndexOptions(name = "_ts", expireAfterSeconds = 20))
    public Date _ts = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4);
```

Do i need to do separate code for creating indexes?

Mongo DB Version: 3.2.22

(I have used ORM tool - hibernate in which we set ddl proeprty as true which auto create tables, does morphia also have same)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ensureIndexes()` on your `Datastore` reference.

Answer (score 0):

In properties file :

```
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62655088/2266070