# Spring boot mongo db index (unique=true) not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have the below class as my document.

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "test")
public class TestData {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String hash;

}
```

Even if I'm using Indexed with unique enabled, I'm able to insert duplicate documents into collection.
But if I generate index in mongo shell then it is working.

Is there any way where I can specify unique Index through code only?

Comment: What's the `error/exception` you are getting ? Please add some error/exception trace.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `unique = true`?

Comment: @Joe yes sorry, I'll update now, it's not working for both true and false.

Comment: @Amitkumar: There is no error, the entry just goes into mongo

Comment: `@Indexed` can't be applied at class level, It should be applied at field level. Use `@CompoundIndex` instead.

Comment: @Amitkumar: Tried that too @CompoundIndex(def = "{ 'hash': 1 }", unique = true) , it's not working

Comment: @Amitkumar: This is a syntax error, can't be done like that.

Comment: See this duplicate question - The `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true` property change worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006818/spring-boot-mongo-wont-create-index-with-the-index-annotation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot / mongo wont create index with the index annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006818/spring-boot-mongo-wont-create-index-with-the-index-annotation)

Answer (score 3):

This is how the compound index is used in my code

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({
@CompoundIndex(name = "name_author_idx", def = "{'name' : 1, 'author' : 1}", unique = true, background = true)})
public class Book implements Transformer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Field(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @Field(name = "qty")
    private Integer qty;

    @Field(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    @Field(name = "created_time")
    private LocalDateTime createdTime = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use following code on application.properties file on spring boot application it will work.

`spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're having a configuration component you should override the autoIndexCreation method like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration 
{
@Override
protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
return true;
}}
```