# Why is Mongodb @Indexed(unique=true) not working?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, indexing

My controller:

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserCreateResponse> createUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserCreateRequest userDto,
                                                         BindingResult result)
            throws InvalidRequestException {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException("Request parameter validation failed");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.createUser(userDto));
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
public UserCreateResponse createUser(UserCreateRequest userDto) {
        return convertEntityToDto(userRepository.insert(convertDtoToEntity(userDto)));
    }

    private User convertDtoToEntity(UserCreateRequest userDto) {
       return modelMapper.map(userDto, User.class);
    }

    private UserCreateResponse convertEntityToDto(User user) {
        return modelMapper.map(user, UserCreateResponse.class);
    }
```

And the model is :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document("User")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String job;
}
```

Repository is just a class extending *MongoRepository*.

When I try to insert 2 User with same **userName** via postman post request, it is adding 2 exactly same item to db even if I specified **@Indexed(unique = true)** to userName field.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it on Java side without breaking indexing function on the field(I want to index userName field to find faster)

Comment: at mongo side, you can create unique index on collection for field userName.

Comment: Here is a similar question with a solution: [Spring boot / mongo wont create index with the index annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006818/spring-boot-mongo-wont-create-index-with-the-index-annotation).  It looks like you may have to enable the index creation functionality explicitly, etc.